# Feature building - phone device type

Tags: dataset, data, feature-engineering

I want to use phone type (e.g., "iPhone 6s", "Lenovo K8 Note", etc.) as a feature in a model.  Does anyone know of a way to obtain release date, price, etc of a phone (besides scraping)?  That seems like it would be more useful than one-hot encoding.

Comment: Maybe a possible solution can be using the contents of web pages that have compared mobile phones to construct a word2vec.

Comment: Have you tried https://opendata.stackexchange.com/?